# Comparando strings capturadas do teclado com Rust

Tags: string, if, rust

Estou tentando aprender Rust e naturalmente estou começando por "*The Book*".
No final do capítulo 3 tem 3 exercícios de lógica simples, e um deles é o clássico conversor de Fahrenheit para Celcius.

Percebi um estranho comportamento para iniciar o bloco `if`. Caso eu não coloque o `.trim()` quando chamo a variável `fahrenheit` que acabou de receber o valor vindo do teclado, ele não entra no `if` (linha 14).

O que me deixa um pouco confuso é que, este simples código que testei no playground roda normalmente retornando `true/false`:

```
fn main() {
    let var1 = "um";
    let var2 = "um";
    let result: bool = var1 == var2;
    
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

Eu imagino que ao pegar algo do teclado, algum caractere é inserido no começo ou final da linha. Alguém sabe algo sobre?

Código:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("## Bem vindo ao conversor de Fahrenheit-2-Celcius! ##");

    let mut loop_control: bool = true;
    while loop_control {
        println!("Insira o valor em graus Fahrenheit ou 'quit' para sair:");
        let mut fahrenheit = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut fahrenheit)
            .expect("Deve ser um valor numérico ou 'quit' para sair.");

        if fahrenheit.trim() == "quit" {
            println!("Saindo... até a próxima!");
            loop_control = false;
        } else {
            let fahrenheit: f64 = fahrenheit.trim().parse().expect("Digite um número.");
            let celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) / 1.8;
            println!("{} fahrenheit é/são {} em celsius.", fahrenheit, celsius);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O método `read_line`, que você está utilizando para ler a entrada do usuário do *stdin*, lê a entrada até encontrar uma quebra de linha – geralmente representada por `\n`.

Veja neste exemplo que a string modificada irá conter a quebra:

```
fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();

    dbg!(input); // [src/main.rs:5] input = "Foo\n"
}
```

Não é de se esperar que uma comparação entre `"Foo"` e `"Foo\n"` retorne `true`. Para corrigir isso, você deve utilizar o método `trim`, que retorna um [*string slice*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-02-strings.html#slicing-strings) onde os extremos estão sem os caracteres de espaço (quebras de linha, espaços, etc).

Com o resultado de `trim`, você estará comparando as strings iguais (já que saberá que a quebra de linha não estará lá).

---

E não precisa chamar o `trim` duas vezes. Basta criar uma variável nova e armazenar o valor retornado pelo método `trim`.

Não tem muito a ver com a pergunta, mas dá para remover o booleano `loop_control` dá jogada ao utilizar um loop infinito e utilizar um `break` para sair quando necessário. [Veja que o código fica bem mais limpo.](https://gist.github.com/rust-play/b54eb9601a5626ce3221b00b338dd3dc)

Comment: Ahhh entendi. Imaginava mesmo que deveria haver algum caracter sendo inserido no começo ou final de linha, mas não estava encontrando. Muito obrigado pela resposta!

Sobre o break estava ciente, é utilizado no cap2 quando programamos o guessing game. Mas como será discutido com mais profundidade no futuro do livro eu decidi não o utilizar mesmo...
Obrigado mais uma vez!